# How can I compile TCLAP and link it with CLUSCO?

Tags: git, github

I need to use an app named [CLUSCO](https://bitbucket.org/mjamroz/clusco/src/master/README.md), whose git is [hosted in BitBucket.](https://bitbucket.org/mjamroz/clusco/src/master/)

This app uses a library called [TCLAP](https://tclap.sourceforge.net/), whose git is [hosted in GitHub](https://github.com/xguerin/tclap).

I tried to follow the [installation instruction](https://github.com/xguerin/tclap/blob/master/INSTALL) supplied by TCLAP, but failed.

> The simplest way to compile this package is:
>
> 1. `cd` to the directory containing the package's source code and type
>    `./configure` to configure the package for your system.  If you're
>    using `csh` on an old version of System V, you might need to type
>    `sh ./configure` instead to prevent `csh` from trying to execute
>    `configure` itself.
>
>    Running `configure` takes a while.  While running, it prints some
>    messages telling which features it is checking for.

I have no clue how to do this.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

EDIT:

I am trying to generate seq.dat and seq.txt files myself, so I can use them with REMO.
I am using mkseq.pl script.

The following was my command:

```
user_name@server_name:~/spatial/reconstruction_tools/remo_v2$ perl 
mkseq.pl /home/spatial/input_pdb/pdb1a6j.pdb 1
PSIPRED finished
user_name@server_name:~/spatial/reconstruction_tools/remo_v2$
```

This command generated four files:

- seq.dat
- protein.fasta
- psitmp27331007f0101.blast
- psitmp27331007f0101.fasta

seq.dat is totally empty. psitmp27331007f0101.blast is also practically empty. seq.txt didn't appear.

Comment: It's not clear where you're stuck. For example did you pass the `cd` step?

Comment: @A.B, thanks for the reply. check the edit.

Comment: I'm stopping here. The question is about a problem for compiling/installing and then you're adding a part about *usage* in bioinformatics environment.